# Why does my Matlab function not accept an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, parameters, parameter-passing

I have the following function:

```
function [ res ] = F( n )
    t = 1.5;
    res = 0;
    if n <= 0
        return;
    end
    for i = 0:n-1
        res = res + power(-1,i)*power(t,2*i+1)/((2*i+1)*factorial(i));
    end 
end
```

I'm trying to pass an array to it so that I could see its output for every point in the array

```
F([2,3,4])
```

For some reason it refuses to act on the whole array, only giving me the output for the first member. 
Why is that?

EDIT: If I change

```
res = 0;
```

at the beginning to

```
res = 0 + n;
res = res - n;
```

It does work for the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is res is not an array. You can do something like this:

```
function res = F(n)
  t = 1.5;
  m = length(n);
  res = zeros(m, 1);
  for  j = 1 : m
    for i = 0 : n(j) - 1
      res(j) = res(j) + power(-1, i) * power(t, 2 * i + 1) / ((2 * i + 1) * factorial(i));
    end; 
  end;
end;
```

The result for your example vector input:

```
>> F([2,3,4])

ans =

   0.375000000000000
   1.134375000000000
   0.727566964285714
```